# Swift: captureSession.sessionPreset custom resolution

Tags: swift, aspect-ratio

In my custom camera I have set:

`captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh`  for ratio 16:9

`captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto` for ratio 4:3

It's possible to create a new custom ratio?

Example

ratio 1:1 (squared)

ratio  1.91:1 (post facebook)

and other ratios.